# decrypt a column in a dataframe Fernet (Token must be bytes)

Tags: python

I am looking to decrypt a column of csv file that I have encrypted using the same key I have used to encrypt that column when I wrote that file. Here is what I am doing :

```
 with open('thekey.key', 'rb') as mykey:
          key = mykey.read()

 f = Fernet(key)

 df =pd.read_csv('codedfile.csv')

 f.decrypt(df['Password'])
```

I am sure that happens because the values type inside Password are strings (although it looks like `b'nqjnnxqwa`), but I do not know how to change them into bytes.

Comment: Please provide [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If the key is written to the file as text then you should read the file as text file (instead of binary file - `rb`):

```
with open('thekey.key', 'rt') as mykey:
      key = mykey.read()
```

Comment: I meant the type of password column `object`. I believe I have to transform it into bytes before I am able to decrypt the column.

Comment: it gives the same answer error by the way

Comment: I think you could use `df['Password'].str`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I used  `df['Password'].str.encode` thinking it was going to change to bytes but it remains `object` type

Comment: You did not provide any data examples and your code is incomplete. Add MWE so that someone can help you out.

Comment: this is exactly what I did. I am reading a csv file where the password column have been encrypted while writing that file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to transform the string to bytes:

```py
df['Password'] = df['Password'].str.encode(encoding='utf-8')
```